Django: first data record not being saved when field = zero
I am new to Django and I am currently struggling to find out the reason the first data record from a formset is not saved (included) into database when the numeric field poQtyof the ProductOrder model is equal to zero.
QueryDict seems to be okay with 4 records in this example, but the first record is not included in the database when productorder_set-0-poQty is zero:
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['6b85qEA4LMz7f3lcUvlpAi74BATLiouApAE1AKLMQhz0I7Gohvmw8jhAHnMf82LT'], 'orderOpen': ['on'], 'orderTable': ['02'], 'menuQuery': ['1'],
'productorder_set-TOTAL_FORMS': ['4'], 'productorder_set-INITIAL_FORMS': ['0'], 'productorder_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS': ['0'], 'productorder_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS': ['1000'], 
'productorder_set-0-prodQuery': ['1'], 'productorder_set-0-poQty': ['0'], 'productorder_set-0-poOrder': [''], 'productorder_set-0-id': [''], 
'productorder_set-1-prodQuery': ['2'], 'productorder_set-1-poQty': ['0'], 'productorder_set-1-poOrder': [''], 'productorder_set-1-id': [''], 
'productorder_set-2-prodQuery': ['4'], 'productorder_set-2-poQty': ['0'], 'productorder_set-2-poOrder': [''], 'productorder_set-2-id': [''], 
'productorder_set-3-prodQuery': ['3'], 'productorder_set-3-poQty': ['0'], 'productorder_set-3-poOrder': [''], 'productorder_set-3-id': ['']}>

I would appreciate some help on that... thanks!
Here are further details:
models.py
class ProductClass(models.Model):
    classDescription = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Type', unique=True, null=True)
    classPrint = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Print?')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Product Classes'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.classDescription
    
class Product(models.Model):
    prodclassQuery = models.ForeignKey(ProductClass, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Product Class', default=1)
    prodDescription = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Product')
    prodPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Price')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['prodclassQuery', 'prodDescription']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.prodDescription

class Menu(models.Model):
    menuActive = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Active?', default=False)
    menuDescription = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Menu')
    prodQuery = models.ManyToManyField(Product, verbose_name='Product')
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['menuDescription', ]
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.menuDescription
    
class Order(models.Model):
    orderDtOpen = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    orderDtClose = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    orderOpen = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name='Open?')
    orderTable = models.CharField(max_length=25, verbose_name='Table')
    menuQuery = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Menu', default=1)
    prodQuery = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='ProductOrder')
    
class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    poOrder = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Order', default=1)
    prodQuery = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Product', default=1)
    poQty = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Quantity')

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=('poOrder', 'prodQuery'), name='once_per_product_order')
        ]

forms.py
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['orderOpen', 'orderTable', 'menuQuery',]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['menuQuery'].queryset = Menu.objects.filter(menuActive=True)

class ProductOrderForm(ModelForm):
    filtered_products = None

    class Meta:
        model = ProductOrder
        fields = ['prodQuery', 'poQty',]
        widgets = {'prodQuery': TextInput}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filtered_products = Product.objects.filter(menu__prodQuery = self.instance.prodQuery)
        self.fields['prodQuery'].queryset = self.filtered_products

views.py
def create_order(request):
    form = OrderForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    filtered_products = ProductOrderForm()
    ProductOrderFormset = inlineformset_factory(Order, Order.prodQuery.through, form = ProductOrderForm, 
                                                extra = len(filtered_products.filtered_products),
                                                can_delete = False)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        order = form.save(commit=False)
        formset = ProductOrderFormset(request.POST, instance=order)
        if formset.is_valid():
            try:  
                order.save()
                formset.save()
                return redirect('/orders')
            except:
                pass
    else:
        formset = ProductOrderFormset(request.POST or None, instance=Order(), 
                                      initial=[{'prodQuery': prod.id} for prod in filtered_products.filtered_products],)
    context = {
        'form': form, 
        'formset': formset,
    }
    return render(request,'create_order.html', context)

template
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% load custom_tags %}
        {{ form.orderOpen.label }} {{ form.orderOpen }}
        {{ form.orderTable.label }} {{ form.orderTable }}
        {{ form.menuQuery.label }} {{ form.menuQuery }}

        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
        
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="{{ form.prodQuery.auto_id }}">
                {% with idx=forloop.counter0 %}
                {% with prod=form.fields.prodQuery.queryset|index:idx %}
                {{ prod.prodclassQuery }} {{ prod }} {{ prod.prodPrice }}            
                {% endwith %}
                {% endwith %}
            </label></th>
            <td>  
                <input type="hidden" name="{{ form.prodQuery.html_name }}" value="{{ form.prodQuery.value }}" cols="80" rows="20" id="{{ form.prodQuery.auto_id }}">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <!--<th><label for="{{ form.poQty.auto_id }}">Quantity:</label></th>-->
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="incrementValue('{{ form.poQty.auto_id }}')">+</button>
                <input type="number" name="{{ form.poQty.html_name }}" value="0" min="0" id="{{ form.poQty.auto_id }}">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="decreaseValue('{{ form.poQty.auto_id }}')">-</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="{{ form.poOrder.html_name }}" id="{{ form.poOrder.auto_id }}">
                <input type="hidden" name="{{ form.id.html_name }}" id="{{ form.id.auto_id }}">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        {% endfor %}
 
    <div>  
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-danger" href="{%url 'urlOrders' %}">Cancel</a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
    </div>

    </form>

PS.: I have decided to "mimic" the inlineformset_factory template in order to add some buttons to increase/ decrease product quantity.

To ensure that the first record is always included, regardless of the value of poQty, you can set extra to 1. This will ensure that at least one extra form is included in the formset, even if poQty is zero for all records.
Use the following view:
def create_order(request):
    form = OrderForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    filtered_products = ProductOrderForm()
    ProductOrderFormset = inlineformset_factory(Order, Order.prodQuery.through, form=ProductOrderForm, 
                                                extra=1, 
                                                can_delete=False)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        order = form.save(commit=False)
        formset = ProductOrderFormset(request.POST, instance=order)
        if formset.is_valid():
            try:  
                order.save()
                formset.save()
                return redirect('/orders')
            except:
                pass
    else:
        formset = ProductOrderFormset(request.POST or None, instance=Order(), 
                                      initial=[{'prodQuery': prod.id} for prod in filtered_products.filtered_products])
    context = {
        'form': form, 
        'formset': formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'create_order.html', context)

So here by setting extra to 1, the formset will always include at least one extra form, even if the poQty field for the first record is zero.
Edit
As you said in the comment, If setting extra=1 is causing issues with loading all product options in the form, you can try a different approach to ensure that the first record is always included, regardless of the value of poQty.
One way to achieve this is by checking if the formset has any data submitted. If there's no data submitted, you can manually add a form for the first product.
So try this:
def create_order(request):
    form = OrderForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    filtered_products = ProductOrderForm()
    ProductOrderFormset = inlineformset_factory(Order, Order.prodQuery.through, form=ProductOrderForm, 
                                                extra=0,  # Set extra to 0 initially
                                                can_delete=False)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        order = form.save(commit=False)
        formset = ProductOrderFormset(request.POST, instance=order)
        if formset.is_valid():
            try:  
                order.save()
                formset.save()
                return redirect('/orders')
            except:
                pass
    else:
        formset = ProductOrderFormset(request.POST or None, instance=Order())
        if not request.POST:
            initial_data = [{'prodQuery': prod.id} for prod in filtered_products.filtered_products]
            formset.forms.append(ProductOrderForm(initial=initial_data))
    context = {
        'form': form, 
        'formset': formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'create_order.html', context)

So now even if no data is submitted, the formset will include a form for the first product.
Edit 2
It seems like the initial argument is expecting a dictionary with keys corresponding to form fields, but it's receiving a list of dictionaries instead.
Try this:
def create_order(request):
    form = OrderForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    filtered_products = ProductOrderForm()
    ProductOrderFormset = inlineformset_factory(Order, Order.prodQuery.through, form=ProductOrderForm, 
                                                extra=0,  # Set extra to 0 initially
                                                can_delete=False)
    if request.POST and form.is_valid():
        order = form.save(commit=False)
        formset = ProductOrderFormset(request.POST, instance=order)
        if formset.is_valid():
            try:  
                order.save()
                formset.save()
                return redirect('/orders')
            except:
                pass
    else:
        formset = ProductOrderFormset(request.POST or None, instance=Order())
        if not request.POST:
            initial_data = [{'prodQuery': prod.id, 'poQty': None} for prod in filtered_products.filtered_products]
            formset.forms.append(ProductOrderForm(initial=data) for data in initial_data)
    context = {
        'form': form, 
        'formset': formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'create_order.html', context)

Another Approach:
You can also try setting the initial quantity for the forms to None instead of 0. This way, Django will recognize them as changed and try to save them, like the following:
else:
    formset = ProductOrderFormset(
        request.POST or None,
        instance=Order(),
        initial=[{'prodQuery': prod.id, 'poQty': None} for prod in filtered_products.filtered_products],
    )


It did not work, unfortunately... when I set extra = 1 I prevent that all product options are loaded in the form. Thanks anyway...

Thanks @Sunderam Dubey, but the line formset.forms.append(ProductOrderForm(initial=initial_data)) is throwing an error: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required

@Eduardo See edit 2 in the answer.

it does not work with extra=0, as no formset value is loaded. When I set min_num to 4 all products are displayed, but still the first one is not saved to database if poQty=0. Question: is it a standard behavior, not saving to database no-changed records? How could I "catch" that and manually changed the record (from zero to zero)? Not an elegant solution but it might work...

@Eduardo ok so I'd think about it when I'll get some time and will reply to you later on.

thanks a lot ! I am changing the approach and saving to the database only those products with poQty>0. Now I am working on a update form which also allows to include missing products. Hope that works!
